# Discord.py Bot Not Leaving Voice Channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to code a discord.py bot but I ran into an issue while trying to get the bot to leave the voice channel. I have been looking online and haven't been able to find a working solution to my problem.

The Libraries that I am using:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import time
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Game
from discord import opus
```

The code that I am using:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def summon(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)

@client.command(name = "check", pass_context=True)
async def check(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    if client.is_voice_connected(server):
        await client.say("Yes")
    else:
        await client.say("No")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    for x in client.voice_clients:
        if(x.server == ctx.message.server):
            return await x.discconect()
    return await client.say("Mission Failed."
```

The error message that I am getting:

```
Ignoring exception in command summon
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)

  File "A:/Python/MossyBot/Bot Version 1.0.py", line 53, in summon
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 3209, in join_voice_channel
    voice = VoiceClient(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 217, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice")

RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling, then reinstalling `pynacl`?

Comment: You misspelled disconnect in your second to last line, and are missing a ) on the final line of code. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The last line tells you what you need to know.

Run a `pip` install for `PyNaCL`, which is required for most voice functions,  like so:

```
pip install pynacl
```